# В чем преимущество неявно извлеченных опционалов передобычными переменными в Swift

Tags: swift

В учебнике по swift 2.1 натолкнулся на такой абзац

> Следующий пример показывает разницу в поведении между опциональной строкой и неявно извлеченной опциональной строкой при доступе к их внутреннему значению как к явной строке:
>
> ```
>    let possibleString: String? = "An optional string."
>    let forcedString: String = possibleString! // необходим восклицательный знак
>
>    let assumedString: String! = "An implicitly unwrapped optional string."
>    let implicitString: String = assumedString // восклицательный знак не нужен
> ```

То есть если мы уверены, что у опционала есть значение, то объявляем его с ! и нам его проще извлекать. Это удобно и хорошо. Однако мне не понятно, почему в таких  случаях нельзя использовать обычную переменную и вообще не касаться опционалов? Есть ли какое то преимущество у неявно извлеченного опционала перед оычной переменной? Я новичок в swift и не имею опыта написания программ на нем, однако есть опыт с другими языками и он подсказывает мне, что разница между неявно извлеченным опционалом и обычной переменной - это дело стиля написания кода. Однако может я ошибаюсь? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вы гарантируете, что на момент использования у неявно извлеченного опционала будет значение. Но на момент объявления, значения еще может не быть:

```
let assumedString: String!
if x > 0 {
    assumedString = "X - положительное число"
} else if x == 0 {
    assumedString = "X равно нулю"
} else {
    assumedString = "X - отрицательное число"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите образец:

```
class Demo
{
    func testPrint()
    {
        print("Test")
    }
}

// 1. Тут все как обычно
var d : Demo = Demo()
d.testPrint()

// 2. Тут тоже как обычно, только синтаксис опциональный
var d_optional : Demo?
d_optional = Demo()
d_optional?.testPrint()

// 3. Опциональный синтаксис, тут мы "забываем" проинициализировать переменную. 
// Ошибки нет, просто не выполняется метод
var d_optional2 : Demo?
d_optional2?.testPrint()

// 4. Обычный синтаксис, тут мы тоже "забываем" проинициализировать переменную. 
// Ошибка компиляции.
var d2 : Demo
d2.testPrint()

// 5. Строгий синтаксис, тут мы тоже "забываем" проинициализировать переменную. 
// Ошибка во время выполнения программы.
var d3 : Demo!
d3.testPrint()
```

Теперь пояснение.

Если значение переменной не критически важно для работы программы, вместо бесконечных if (item != nil) мы можем просто объявить item как опциональную переменную (знак ?). 
Т.е. код пункта 2 выглядел бы примерно так:

```
var d : Demo
var d = Demo()
if (d != nil)
{
    d.testPrint()
}
```

Если опциональная переменная не будет проинициализированна, то просто ничего не будет выполнено. Так мы сильно сокращаем количество кода и нервов.

Если мы укажем переменную как обязательную (знак !) то мы уже сами должны следить за тем чтобы в ней были данные.

Если я что-то не так сам понял, прошу меня поправить.